# Hide sharePoint list Columns based on users permissions

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery

I want to hide SharePoint list(Three columns) from users. The columns are only see by HR manager and V/Manager. How to Achieve?

I just tried like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;


    if (xml.search('Service Desk Operators') == -1)
     {

       $("select[title=Status;Approves;]").parent().parent().parent().hide(); 

$('nobr:contains("Status","approves")').closest('tr').hide();
   }  
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to down the path of finding the correct `TD` within the ListView.

The ListView webpart is going to render a `TABLE` element with a `summary` attribute that will help you target the correct table.  That is step 1.

Assuming that you want to target the 4th column, you could write something like this (CSS):

```
table[summary=YourGridName] tbody tr td:nth-child(4) { display:none; }
```

If you wanted to write some JavaScript for this, you could try this:

```
if (hideHRColumns()) { 
    /* your code goes in the 'hideHRColumns' function and returns boolean */
    $("table[summary=YourGridName] tbody tr td:nth-child(4)").empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute selector should have "", for example:

```
 $('select[title="StatusApproves"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same code with a few modifications in it and it is working fine for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // site relative url 
        site = "sites/test"
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
                userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
                    webUrl = site
                }),
                webUrl = site
                async: false,
                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                    //If the current User does belong to the group "Service desk Operators"
                    if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Service desk Operators']").length == 1) {
                        alert("User exists");
                        $("select[title=Status;Approves;]").parent().parent().parent().hide();

                        $('nobr:contains("Status","approves")').closest('tr').hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```