# How to grant permissions at the column level Document Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, permissions, column

I'm using SharePoint 2013

I have a document library in which I would like to grant permissions at the column level, I mean that I want to show certain users some columns and not all.

I've been consulting about this but I can't find any documentation to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set column level permissions in SharePoint.

1. There are ways to show and hide columns, but we can't set column level permissions in SP.
   1.1:  Creating a SharePoint View: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9
2. There are workarounds (hacks) to set permissions on Views, but it's not the column level permissions you are looking for.
   2.2: Example:  https://www.netwoven.com/2016/01/21/how-to-set-view-level-permission-for-a-listlibrary-in-sharepoint/

Comment: You can give me an example of how to hide the columns to give validity to your answer ?

Comment: Can I hide the columns from certain users/groups?

Comment: Out of the box, you can't fully set permissions on a column.  You can use Views to show data, then you can use custom forms (InfoPath) to only allow users to interact with certain fields.  InfoPath is going away, but there's no end to what you can do with the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Granting column level permissions is not possible in SharePoint.

As you are using SharePoint 2013, you can use custom solution to check the permissions of currently logged in user & hide the columns using jQuery & SharePoint REST APIs.

Check below references for more information related to suggested workaround:

1. [How to hide a column for some users or groups](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117149/how-to-hide-a-column-for-some-users-or-groups/214281)
2. [Hide sharePoint list Columns based on users permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232914/hide-sharepoint-list-columns-based-on-users-permissions)
3. [Hide SharePoint list columns based on user permissions](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/hide-sharepoint-list-columns-based-on-user-permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no column level permission in SharePoint.I have a solution for your reference, use jsom to determine whether the current user has permission, and then use csr to hide the column.

[Check If User has Full Control Permission In a Web In SharePoint 2016](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/check-if-user-has-full-permission-in-a-web-in-sharepoint-2016)

[Hide column from SharePoint list view using CSR.](https://riptutorial.com/sharepoint/example/26699/hide-column-from-sharepoint-list-view-using-csr-)